# How to fix 'SDK client path is invalid' error in Thycotic Secret Server's API

Tags: python-3.x

I use Thycotic's Secret Server and am utilizing their API to query the password field of a secret. While using the API, I am receiving a `SDK client path is invalid` error.

Once I configured the connection (you only need to do it once according to the API documentation located at https://github.com/thycotic/secret-server-python), I then execute the query using:

```
from secret_server.sdk_client import SDK_Client

  client = SDK_Client()

  akey = client.commands.get_secret(1234, field='password').strip()

  skey = client.commands.get_secret(4321, field='password').strip()
```

I expected to simply get my secrets when I print my `akey` and `skey` variables, but instead I get the error:

```
   raise ValueError('SDK client path is invalid')
ValueError: SDK client path is invalid
```

What's interesting is that I have to run the configure command again to get it to work. I figure that's because when you actually go to configure the connection you specify the full path to your SDK client and you don't have to after you've already done it once.

Regardless, when I do, I get a `machine is already initialized` (as expected) response, and it then works. But you shouldn't have to do that. Plus, that would be an issue because the onboarding key will be stored in the code, and we can't have that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just noting for future that referenced SDK has been superseded by one [here](https://github.com/thycotic/python-tss-sdk) that is also published to PyPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error; except I never got past the invalid SDK path.

I solved it by doing this:
Script A) init as outlined in the sdk documentation (only run once)
Script B)

```
client = SDK_Client()
client.config.SDK_CONFIG["path"] = path_to_my_sdk
key = client.commands.get_secret(1234, field = 'password')
```

Adding that middle line is what resolved the problem.  I'll log this as an issue in the github that the init process apparently is not saving the path.

Comment: I don't work for that company anymore, but thanks so much for answering this. That's awesome.